# Jinja2 marking HTML string as safe

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a HTML tag in jinja2 that I want to embed a variable into.

Format.html:

```
{% set color="red" %}
{% set tag="<img src='{{ color }}.png' />" %}
This is red {{ tag|safe }}.
```

If I mark `tag` as safe, it doesn't render the variable `color`. If I don't render it as safe it sanitizes the HTML img tag and I can't embed my image. How do I properly embed my image ? I don't want to write out the img tag because I need it as a reusable variable throughout the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use`{{ }}` inside another template tag. You can, however, concatenate the string and the variable `color` inside a template tag like this:

**Method #1:** Using the `~` symbol. From Jinja2's [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#other-operators), it converts the variables into strings and concatenates them.

```
{% set tag = "<img src='" ~  color ~ ".png' />" %}
```

OR

**Method #2:** Using the [format](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#format) filter:

```
{% set tag = "<img src='%s.png' />"|format(color) %}
```